# Installing 'multiscorer' library in PYTHON without pip

Tags: python-3.x

friends
I need to nstalling 'multiscorer' library in PYTHON without pip
and I can't find the source code and I don't know how I would install the source code.

I tried "pip install multiscorer"
And I expect to execute "from multiscorer import Multiscorer"